Extracting a 24x24 icon associated with file type
I'm trying to extract five formats (sizes) of icons that are associated with common file types (e.g. PDF files, DOCX, XLSX, etc.).
I've scraped through countless posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere; all explain various techniques of extracting associated icons, and each technique has its limitations. (example)
For stock icons (e.g. folders), the best way to extract all image formats is to use SHGetStockIconInfo function to get the stock icon's file location and icon index, then by calling SHDefExtractIcon I am able to extract the desired icon sizes.
For common file types, I've tried various techniques. Most Win32 functions are limited to only two image formats, small (16x16) and large (32x32). Im sure that in Windows11 almost all standard icons have the image formats like 24x24 and 64x64 available with them. Some internet posts have explained using SHGetFileInfo to identify the file path that contains the icon; this doesn't seem to work with Windows11 and .NET Framework 4.8.
The approach I'm using to get more icon sizes is that I'm using SHGetFileInfo with SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX and SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flags, followed by SHGetImageList to extract various icon size. But even this technique is limited to following icon sizes: 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, and 128x128. I tried manually resizing a higher image resolution to achieve 24x24 and 64x64, but it results in slightly blurry images.

Here the icons 16,32 and 48 are directly extracted through native shell functions; while the 24 is resized from 32, and 64 is resized from 128; which look blurry.
My question is: I'm sure the common icons available in the Windows11 system have the 24x24 and 64x64 image formats built into the icon library files; how do I extract these icons? It would be great to be able to extract an icon associated with a file extension (for which file does not need to exist) which is the size of 16, 24, 32, 48 and 64.

Interesting. Because I just noticed that Windows store assets generated in UWP do not include 64x64 or 128x128. (The VS scaling does a fairly good job otherwise taking a large image and generating store assets for 16x16, and up ... to "splash screens").

@KJ I don't have Acrobat installed on my system. The default PDF viewer for me is the Microsoft Edge browser. Now scraping through Windows Registry to identify the DefaultIcon for the PDF file extensions, I came to see that the default icon is obtained from MSEdge.exe file using icon index of 13. And if I open this icon on an icon development app, it contains all sorts of sizes, including 24 and 64.

My last resort is to identify default icons by directly reading Windows Registry (using the steps explained here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-show-default-extension-icon-instead-of/3ed3b66d-c292-4188-8d1e-3416f7086694) and then read the desired icon formats using shell functions. But I find this to be a flimsy and feel it may not be the best solution across various computer configurations.

Instead of relying upon the Win32 shell functions, I resorted to tracing the default icons for file types through Registry, and then extracting the desired icon sizes.

See the difference, the first row comprises of images extracted using shell functions, in which the 24x24 (second icon) and 64x64 icon (last icon) are blurry because shell functions do not support this icon size even if icon exists.
The second row is my revised procedure which involves reading default icon from registry (see this) to identify the EXE or DLL which contains the icon and its icon index, then calling SHDefExtractIcon using the various icon sizes to extract the correct icon image. Works great for now, will try on sandbox systems to see if it works there.

A problem with this approach in WIndows11 is that sometimes default icons (e.g. text files) are associated with apps installed from Microsoft Store. In such cases, the DefaultIcon value specified in registry is @{Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2405.13.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsNotepad/Files/Assets/txtfile.png} which means this is not a traditional ICON file, its a PNG, which requires further parsing and resizing, and a whole new world.
